# jQuery with Nested Tables, select outer table tr/td with passed Selector

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to setup a nested table function. So within the function I am passing a selected element and I want to select only the children/direct-descendants `td`/`tr` of that table and NOT the nested table's `td`/`tr` elements. Here is a little example that I setup.

```
<table class="top">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>
            <table class="nested">
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="results"></div>
```

and the jQuery / Javascript to go with it...

```
var tbl = $(".top");
var r = $("div#results");

$(r).html("");

$(r).append("var tbl = $(\".top\")</br>")

$(r).append("$(tbl).find(\"td\").length:" + $(tbl).find("td").length.toString() + "</br>");

$(r).append("$(\"td\", tbl).length: " + $("td", tbl).length.toString() + "</br>");

$(r).append("$(tbl).children(\"tbody\").children(\"tr\").children(\"td\").length: " + $(tbl).children("tbody").children("tr").children("td").length.toString() + "</br>");
```

The results are as follows...

var tbl = $(".top") **(to simulate the passed selector)**

$(tbl).find("td").length:12 **(selects ALL td elements)**

$("td", tbl).length: 12 **(selects ALL td elements, same as above)**

$(tbl).children("tbody").children("tr").children("td").length: 6 **(selects the proper elements, but the jQuery chain seems too long and strict for what I want to do)**

Any help to find the proper selector for the children elements of the top level table is much appreciated! Thanks!

Update: here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheJoeFletch/7gzKa/3/).

Comment: You mean something like $(".top > TR > TD")?

Comment: @Tim: No, that will not work since there is a `tbody` element between and since the `.top` element is passed via a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working fiddle using direct descendant (`>`) selector: http://jsfiddle.net/3T9sN/

```
$(function(){
    var rows = $(".top > TBODY > TR");
    alert( "Number of rows: " + rows.length );

    var cells = $(".top > TBODY > TR > TD");
    alert( "Number of cells : " + cells.length );
});​
```

Of course, you can reuse some of the contexts here to make the query more efficient, such as:

```
var tbody = $(".top > tbody");

// using children() method
var rows = tbody.children( "TR" );

// using selector context
var cells = $( "> TR > TD", tbody );

alert( "Number of rows: " + rows.length );
alert( "Number of cells : " + cells.length );
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3T9sN/1/

Comment: I thought that I tried `$("> tbody > tr > td", tbl)`, but I guess I missed it! Thanks for the reply. This works for what I want to do. A lot shorter and quicker to write.

Answer (score 0):

Pass parent in addition to your selector to find your elements in children

```
     $("what your looking for ", parent);
```

Same as

```
     $(parent).children("what you are looking for")
```

The first is much shorter syntax

Comment: Thanks, but those two statements do **NOT** provide the same results.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tbl = $('.top');
var stuff = tbl.find('table').filter(function(){
  $('#results').append($('tr, td', this).length);
});
```

Normally, you would use a return in the filter function, but we don't want to return the elements, we want to use data abstracted from them. For this, do not use the 'return' method.

[Standard-issue jsFiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/qfKhJ/)

Comment: The code as listed returns the nested `table`'s `tr` and `td` elements. I updated the code to show what I am talking about. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheJoeFletch/qfKhJ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

`$('tr:not(tr tr)')`. Probably slower than using descendant selector, but much more flexible.